# Rails precompile assets on Heroku Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I try to deploy my simple Rails app to Heroku. This app is just attempt to use bower with Heroku.

Unfortunately I have problems with precompile assets on Heroku.
This gives me error `Sprockets::FileNotFound`.

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file './app/App'
remote:        (in /tmp/build_fe6dc0e2c0063705b279b26e4aa2432d/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:12)
```

I don't know what can be the cause. `App.js` is my own file and it surely exists.

Need to mention that `rake assets:precompile` work properly on my local machine.

This is my `applications.js` which includes all other files

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require vendor/angular/angular
//= require vendor/angular-route/angular-route
//= require vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource
//= require vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize

//= require vendor/moment/moment
//= require vendor/angular-moment/angular-moment

//= require      ./app/App
//= require      ./app/router
//= require_tree ./app/controllers
//= require_tree ./app/directives
//= require_tree ./app/filters
```

In some similar questions I found advice to run `heroku repo:purge_cache`.
But this failed to me too.

```
~/tmp/repo_tmp $ cd unpack
~/tmp/repo_tmp/unpack $ tar -zxf ../repo-cache.tgz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

All source code is published at GitHub
https://github.com/ivanovalexey/bowerrr

Could some one help me figure it out?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was with file name `./app/App.js`. I renamed it to `./app/main.js` and it worked. Still wonder why it doesn't matter locally.